# Can I read content of the oldest element in a Queue without ruining thread safety?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

Removing an element from my queue depends on the content of the element.
In order to access the content the only suggested way is via `myQueue.get()` method.

The content of a queue can be also accessed in that way `myQueue.queue[0]` though. Which translates to reading content directly from the underlying `deque`. That means that reading content that way doesn't offer the thread safety privilege that queue is originally created for.

Is there a thread-safe way to read the content without removing the element?

Comment: Quick question: If you remove an element from a queue according to its content, then you would have elements in your queue forever, which means the queue is blocked? So why do you insert the element in the queue in the first place? And why would you want to keep it in?

Comment: Eventually the element will be removed, the content contains a timestamp and given a certain amount of time this timestamp will be expired and the element will be removed

Comment: Not sure if you can do this with a queue, or even if this is a behavior compatible with the notion of queue. You could use some sort of global memory, like a global dict in dev, or a Redis db. You could also (depending on the number of objects) get all elements from the queue and store them in a cache inside your thread function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to adapt the solution shown below. It allows you to get an element if the element satisfies some condition. Your question did not make it clear how you wanted to handle blocking, timeouts, or the inability to find a matching item. As such, the following code is nonblocking and returns a default value when the oldest value does not match the given condition. Please modify the code to fit your particular usage scenario.

```
import queue


class Queue(queue.Queue):

    def get_if(self, condition, default=None):
        with self.not_empty:
            if not self._qsize():
                raise queue.Empty
            if condition(self._peek()):
                item = self._get()
                self.not_full.notify()
                return item
            return default

    def _peek(self):
        return self.queue[0]


def main():
    my_queue = Queue()
    for number in range(100, 200):
        my_queue.put_nowait(number)
    number = my_queue.get_if(lambda item: not item % 10)
    print(number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```